# MapView does not render Maps, but shows location and markers

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an application which uses google maps API to show the location of the device, and show a bunch of markers to the user. I don't get an error on my code and the entire app is working just fine, including the GPSlocation tracking.

My problem is that the MapView does not render the actual map background. With that I mean the streets, street names, etc, but it render the position of the device(with a blue dot), the direction i am facing(with a blue arrow near the blue dot) and all the markers(that i'm dinamically creating from an ArrayList).

The problem possibly is that I have more than one map on the application.

I have provided three screenshots, one of each map instance, for you guys to analyse, and will provide below the java code and XML for each one of them, respectively.

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Ukw.jpg

First Image Code and XML:

XML so that the words can appear above the MapView(Remember, this one used to work, but stopped working after I added the third one):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapInfoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tipo"
        android:text="Tipo"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_nome"
        android:text="Nome"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_above="@id/tv_tipo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for first map, CreateMap() method:

```
private void createMap(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, View v) {
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapInfoView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;

            // For showing a move to my location button
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
            LatLng prestador = new LatLng(Singleton.latitude, Singleton.longitude);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(prestador).title(Singleton.nome_empresa).snippet(Singleton.endereco));

            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(prestador).zoom(16).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            googleMap.setPadding(800, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

XML for second Map, the one that shows all the markers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapCompletoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code for second map:

```
private void createMap(Bundle savedInstanceState, View v) {
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapCompletoView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(Singleton.ContextMainActivity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;

            // For showing a move to my location button
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
            LatLng dispositivo = new LatLng(Singleton.user_latitude,Singleton.user_longitude);

            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(dispositivo).zoom(16).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            googleMap.setPadding(800,0,0,0);
            if(Singleton.tipo_de_busca == "online"){
                for(Prestador p : Singleton.lista_prestadores_online){
                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(p.latitude);
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(p.longitude);
                    try {
                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(p.nome_empresa).snippet(p.telefone).position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.toString();
                    }
                }
            }else{
                for(Prestador p : Singleton.lista_prestadores_offline){
                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(p.latitude);
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(p.longitude);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(p.nome_empresa).snippet(p.telefone)).setPosition(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

XML for third map, the one that only shows the location of the device:
The toast message is called everytime the LocationListener callback the OnLocationChanged method, printing out the current Latitude and Longitude.

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapLocalSetup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@color/mainText"/>
```

Code for the third map:

```
private void createMap(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mapLocalSetup = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapLocalSetup);
    mapLocalSetup.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapLocalSetup.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(Singleton.ContextMainActivity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mapLocalSetup.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;

            // For showing a move to my location button
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            LatLng dispositivo = new LatLng(Singleton.user_latitude, Singleton.user_longitude);

            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(dispositivo).zoom(16).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    });
}
```

So as you can see, all three codes are practically the same, I only call the different ID.
More info:

- The first and the second map are Fragments, The third one is in the launcher activity
- As I said before, the first one used to work fine, but the other two didn't. So what I did was generate another Google Maps API Key using the Google Console, vie the build-in hyperlink inside the google_maps_api_key.xml. After I changed it to the new key, the first map stopped working, and reverting to the old key doesn't fix it.
- I also tried creating and entire new project on the Google Console API, and using that new key but the problem persists.
- So the question is if it's possible to have multiple MapViews on a single application.

-If i would guess anything, i would say that probably the fact that one of the maps is running when I call another one is the reason everything stopped working, but I don't know how to "close" the map.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try calling `mMapView.onResume();`  in `onMapReady()`.

Comment: Just tried it and the problem persists